# Why is class 'large' is only added to the last element of the array?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website that looks like below.
When a text is clicked, the clicked text will get a class called large and the text size will change to 25pt. To see how I am assigning the event and the class large, please look at the js code. The problem I have is when the text "I like swimming" is clicked the large class gets added to the text "I like basketball". Why is this happening? Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

```js
const arraySportsText = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('sportsText'));
for (index in arraySportsText) {
  arraySportsText[index].addEventListener("click", () => arraySportsText[index].classList.add('large'))
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 15pt;
}

.large {
  font-size: 25pt;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Sports</h1>


  <p class="sportsText">I like swimming</p>

  <p class="sportsText">I like basketball</p>

  <script src="scripts/hobby.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `for(` **`let`** `index in arraySportsText)`...

Answer (score 2):

Your loop variable is not explicitly declared, so it gets an implicit `var` declaration as a Global variable.

Your use of the loop variable in the event handler creates [a closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#creating_closures_in_loops_a_common_mistake) around `index` and so when those handlers run (later), they access the last value of that loop variable and so only the last element is affected.

**Use [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) to declare your loop variable with block scope to solve the problem.**

- Addtionally, [don't use `.getElementsByClassName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474) and instead
  use `.querySelectorAll()`.
- And, both `.getElementsByClassName()` and `.querySelectorAll()`
  return collections which are array-like, so neither one of those
  needs `Array.from()` if you are going to use a counting loop to
  iterate it.
- And, `for/in` loops should not be used on Arrays as they enumerate
  all the properties of the Array, not just the indexes. [`for/in`
  should only be used on objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).
- Lastly, the collection that `.querySelectorAll()` returns can be
  looped over with the [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method, removing the
  need for the counting loop.

So, the reworked code really should be:

```js
// Looping over the collection returned from .querySelectorAll()
// eliminates the need for a counting loop, which also removes
// the need to use that index in the event handler, which in turn,
// eliminates the closure problem you had in the first place.
document.querySelectorAll('.sportsText').forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener("click", () => element.classList.add('large'))
});
```

```css
body   { font-size: 15pt; }
.large { font-size: 25pt; }
```

```html
<h1>Sports</h1>
<p class="sportsText">I like swimming</p>
<p class="sportsText">I like basketball</p>
```